Pointer confusion with microdata
When I read the rather sparse documentation and examples regarding microdata under schema.org, I can't tell the difference between markup for an actual item versus a pointer to the item.
Say I have an essay on one web page. I am fairly sure that I would mark up the contents on that page as, say, CreativeWork. If I then have a separate web page with a link (and other metadata) to the essay page, is that also marked up as a CreativeWork? I can find no schema.org category for a reference to a Thing. If I do mark up the reference as a CreativeWork, how would an algorithm reading the microdata differentiate between the page with the essay and the reference to the essay? I could equate them with sameAs, but the two are not really equivalent, since one has the content and the other not.
